# Testing audio player on espresso

Tags: android, android-espresso, android-livedata

I am writing some test for a project that I have been working on in which I have to test the buttons of an audio player. This is the code I have written

```
fun test {
    val data = fakeAudioLibrary.initializeAudioPlayer()  //here data is a livedata
    launch<AudioFragmentTestActivity>(
      createAudioFragmentTestIntent(
        internalProfileId
      )
    ).use {
      it.onActivity {
        data.observeForever{ }    /*Problem here*/
      }
      onView(withId(R.id.ivPlayPauseAudio)).perform(click())
      onView(withId(R.id.ivPlayPauseAudio)).check(matches(withContentDescription("Pause")
        
    }
  }
```

This test fails but when I write

```
it.onActivity {
  data.observeForever {
     if(it.isCompleted()) {
       onView(withId(R.id.ivPlayPauseAudio)).perform(click())
      onView(withId(R.id.ivPlayPauseAudio)).check(matches(withContentDescription("Pause")
     }
  }
```

I read about it [here](https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/unit-testing-livedata-and-other-common-observability-problems-bb477262eb04) and I think it should work both ways.

Can someone please explain to me why this is happening?